# Android Dialog Height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I'm trying to setup a simple dialog, but I can't seem to control the height.  It's always max screen height.  Is there some way to get it to properly wrap to the contents?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@android:string/cancel"
        android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonSave"
        style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.save_dialog);
dialog.setTitle(R.string.saveAs);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Try add `dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` before showing the dialog. Works for `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Scratch that: You have `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in your XML. This forces your Button to be positioned at the very bottom of the space available it has available to it, effectively making the `RelativeLayout` have a match_parent layout_height behavior instead of wrap_content. Why not just use a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"`?

Comment: That is one of the few things I didn't adjust, so that may make some sense, but if so: what an awful design!  The reason I'm using `RelativeLayout` is because there will be a dozen more things in the dialog and I'll rarely use `LinearLayout` for complex layouts (penalties with nested layouts, etc).  The above is what I cut it minimally down to before finally going "WTF!?!?!?", lol.  I'll test in about two hours and follow up.

Comment: @Patrick You are indeed correct about the `alignParentBottom`.  I'll be submitting this as a bug as this is basically undefined behavior.  A child is causing a parent to disregard it's layout setting.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it's a little strange. I think I'll write up an official answer for anyone else with the same issue. Are you able to post the full XML file? There are different ways to solve the problem depending on what you're trying to achieve. (E.g. When I first encountered the issue, I wanted to put a AppBarLayout at the bottom of the dialog that stayed there while the rest of the layout was scroll able)

Comment: I meant to ask you to do that in the prior comment, I'll select it when it's ready.  I submitted the bug report:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=209945&thanks=209945&ts=1463314223

Comment: @Patrick Don't forget to submit an answer so I can select it.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll write one now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in your XML. This forces your `Button` to be positioned at the very bottom of the space it has available to it, effectively making the `RelativeLayout` have a `match_parent` `layout_height` behavior instead of a `wrap_content` one.

An alternative would be to use a `LinearLayout` or a `GridLayout` instead.
Something along the lines of this would do the trick:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- 
    The rest of your layout can go here 
    with a layout_height of 0dp and a layout_weight of 1
    if you want your buttons to dock themselves at the bottom of the dialog
    -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel"
            android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
            style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```